# List ID of a publication list in Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, publicationlist

Is there somewhere that the list ID property of a publication list is displayed in the Marketing Cloud?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no possibility to show the ID as a separate column in the list overview at the moment, but if you only need the IDs of a small number of Lists you can do this without querying the api:

Go to **Email Studio** -> **Subscribers** -> **Publication Lists** and click on the list name of the desired list. From the subscribers overview for this list you can navigate to the properties via the breadcrumbs menu (looks like this: Publication Lists > [YOUR LIST NAME] > Subscribers). If you hover over this link to the properties page (the one with the name of your list), you should see a link in your browser's statusbar that contains the list ID as parameter to a javascript function: `javascript:viewListProperties(123);`

**Edit:** I recently created an extension for Google Chrome, that has some helpful features for Marketing Cloud users. One of which adds the Publication List Ids to the Marketing Cloud UI just with a click of a button. Maybe you like to try it out:

- [Download via Google Chrome Webstore: Salesforce Marketing Cloud - Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-marketing-clou/bkmmmgaljahinmpijhdggabkdngpadbn?hl=en-US)
- [Check out the code on github](https://github.com/mslabina/sfmc-chrome-devtools)

This is what it looks like after the id's are retrieved and added to the interface:
[image: Publication Lists with IDs]

Comment: Good solution, also if you try to Export the publication list a popup confirmation screen will come up that displays the list ID.

Comment: Thanks @AnonWonderer! That was the simplest answer by far

Answer (score 0):

You should go into **Email Studio** -> **Subscribers** -> **Publication List**, then you could select your publication list and click the button **Properties**.

Here you can flag the field **Public** in order to show this publication in the profile/preference center.

Comment: Thanks. I thought ListID would be displayed in the properties but it isn't showing up there. I ended up querying against the _ListSubscribers view and found it that way. I need the ListID value to add to another query to manage our multi-brand account management data flow. I had hoped the ListIDs were just visibly displayed in the properties as they are for regular subscriber lists.

Answer (score 0):

Originally shared as a comment to [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/154229/61264) by @AnonWonderer. Just presenting it as an answer here for visibility, because it was *exactly* what I was looking for.

1. Go **Publication List** in **Email Studio** like usual
2. Click on the publication list that you want the ID of
3. Select **Export** (near the top left of the publication list's records)
4. Copy the the **ID** that shows up (see picture for example)

[image]

5. Hit **Cancel** and go fix yourself a well earned tea or something. SFMC is hard.