# Querying Suppression List by ListID

Tags: suppressionlist

I am trying to query a suppression list via ID but don't know how to get the correct ID.

Tried doing this one but I believe it only applies to publication list:
[List ID of a publication list in Salesforce Marketing Cloud](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154185/list-id-of-a-publication-list-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find Suppression list ID by following below steps:
Go to Email Studio > Subscribers > Suppression lists > Select the list for which you want to find the ID > Click Import button > On 'Import Subscriber Wizard' you will find the list ID

Comment: Thank you for the response and apologies for asking it incorrectly but I am trying to get an "auto-suppression configurion" list ID under Admin > Send Management. I cannot see any ID in properties.

Comment: Marketing Cloud treats Auto Suppression Configurations as Data Extensions. So, I believe you can write a same query as you do for a data extension.