# How to remove a record from a publication list using scripting

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

Can please help me to how to remove a particular record from publication using scripting(ssjs/api ampscript)

Thanks,
Shiva

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to call the [Subscriber](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/subscriber.htm) object using SOAP API.

If you're doing this from a CloudPage, WSProxy will be the easiest solution:

```
<script runat="server">    
Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");

var subkey = "" //provide Sunscriber Key
var email = "" //provide Email Address
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var sub = {
        SubscriberKey: subkey,
        EmailAddress: email,
        Lists: [{
            ID: "" //provide List ID
               }]
         };

var resp = prox.deleteItem("Subscriber", sub);

Write("Response: " + Stringify(resp));
</script>
```

If you don't know how to find the List ID of your Publication List, look at this [thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154185/list-id-of-a-publication-list-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud) (thank you Markus).