# All Subscribers search is not showing all the attribute values from data extension ,despite data extension having values

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, search, subscriber-key

Using SFMC-SOAP API I was able to do the following

### Steps that were successfully done prior to hitting the problem:

1. Create a DataExtension where we had 3 distinct attributes namely `Subscriber Key`, `First Name` and `Last Name`.
2. Then Post successful DataExtension creation, able to successfully create an import definition. Programmatically able to import the values from an xls sheet. As of now I am able to see the values imported successfully into data extension as

   SubscriberKey = 10001, 
   First Name = Rajesh,
   Last Name = Natarajan, 
   Email = Rajesh@mycompany.com
3. Then able to generate an email definition where the email template is correctly associated with data extension that is programmatically defined.
4. I am able to send an email to the associated email that is defined in data extension and i received successfully the email in my email box .

### What is the problem that I am facing?

The data extension has all values which is part of subscribers--> Data Extension Link. While going to Subscribers -->All Subscribers Link and search with the Subscriber key 100001, I am able to see the value as a record post search that enlists email=Rajesh@mycompany.com.But clicking on the attributes tab of the record ,the values that were programmatically set are all blank i.e First Name =   and Last Name =   . None of the attributes that are programmatically set in data extension is listed as values . Hence my downstream process which expects those attributes are all failing values

Can anyone help in permanently setting data extension values and make it listed in Subscriber--> All Subscriber link?

Answer (score 2):

Data Extension values are completely separate from All Subscribers and it was built that way on purpose. In order to force the information inside of a Data Extension into All Subscribers, you will need to export the info from the Data Extension and then import it into Subscribers.

There are a few ways to import into All Subscribers, including:

1. SSJS via [Subscriber.Update](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_subscriberUpdate.htm), or [Subscriber.Upsert](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_subscriberUpsert.htm)
2. Via [SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/updating_subscriber_attributes_using_the_update_method.htm) (or WSProxy) using Update Method
3. or (Recommended for Bulk Updates) via Automation

I personally recommend Option 3, unless it is very light volume/frequency.  Basically what it would be is:

1. Data Extract of your Data Extension
2. File Transfer of the Extract to your FTP
3. Import Activity into All Subscribers.

[image]

Inside your Import Activity you should make sure to correctly map the names of the fields to ensure all the data is passed in correctly.

Answer (score 0):

@Gortonington
Your 3rd suggestion was partially helpful , What i did to solve over and above your suggestion is the following Post my successful data extension, past step 2.

2B. I created a second soap api request where i selected All SUbscribers . I got the id from the properties of All subscribers . I set that ID in the SOAP payload request .

2C.Then I was able to create a second import definition which points to All Subscribers . Then I was able to import the data .

As such two steps one creating data extension structure which is needed for email definition and the other step is to create All subscriber list using SOAP API , and programmatically importing the data . I now see the attribute list populated.

Thank you @GorToNington with your timely help. Hope my appended answer helps others .

p.s : For getting the ID for All subscribers , I struggled for few hours ,then this link where publication list being mentioned was helpful to get the id
[List ID of a publication list in Salesforce Marketing Cloud](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154185/list-id-of-a-publication-list-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud)