# Add subscriber to publication list on link clicking using Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, cloudpage, marketingcloudapi

If subscriber clicks on link in email template, the subscriber data from 'All subscribers' gets added to publication list upon clicking.

How to add the subscriber in the publication link upon clicking the link?

Comment: I am not sure on your actual requirement... but you can use this snippet to achieve similar to the requirement something you are looking at!...https://sfmc-vp.quip.com/I67dAb65z8GG/Adding-subscriber-to-publication-list ...Also you need to install a Chrome extension to get your publication list's ID ... https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154185/list-id-of-a-publication-list-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud

Comment: Thanks for the code @VishalKumarCV . This worked.